# First isomorphism theorem in vector spaces: does "well-definedness" imply uniqueness?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my Linear Algebra class I was introduced to the first isomorphism theorem between vector spaces in a way I didn't find anywhere else.
Quoting the statement:

> Given two vector spaces $V,Z$ and a linear map $T\colon V\to Z$, there exists a unique injective linear map $\tilde{T}\colon V/\ker T\to Z$ such that $\tilde{T}(\pi(x))=T(x)$ (where $\pi\colon V\to V/\ker T$ is the canonical projection onto the quotient space).

$\tilde{T}$ is defined as $\ker T+x\mapsto T(x)$.

Now, I'm having trouble with proving the uniqueness of $\tilde{T}$.
In the proof we were given, there's the rather obscure statement «*since it is well-defined, it is unique*».
But how can it be?
I know that a linear map is unique given its action on a basis, but here we do not even mention a basis of $V/\ker T$.
So are there other methods to prove it?

Comment: In order to get $\tilde{T}(\pi(x))=T(x)$ you must define $$\tilde{T}(vW)=T(v).$$ However, I don't think it is well defined and injective in general.

Comment: Something looks wrong here. You need to assume $W=\ker T$, or something of this sort.

Comment: Yes! Of course, what a mistake. Of course it is the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "since it is well-defined, it is unique" is certainly misleading.
Uniqueness is shown (independently from existence = being well-defined) as follows: Assume $U\colon V/W\to Z$ is another linear map such that also $U(\pi(x))=T(x)$. Then $U=\tilde T$ because for any $y\in V/W$ there exists $x\in V$ such that $y=\pi(x)$ and then $U(y)=U(\pi(x))=T(x)=\tilde T(\pi(x))=\tilde T(y)$.
Note specifically that we did not use any properties of $T$ for uniqueness, whereas well-definedness *does* require some additional properties ...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing hypotheses, I think the following can be said about "since it is well-defined, it is unique". It is definitely not a very clear way of saying whatever is meant. I note first that in mathematical language uniqueness is not in general taken to imply existence: saying "an element with property $P$ is unique" means that at most one element $e$ makes $P(e)$ hold, but it does not claim such$~e$ exists. However changing to the definite article "the element with property $P$ is unique" does implicitly make the existence claim.

Now one is dealing here with a *map* $\tilde T$, which is specified by prescribing its values at arbitrary arguments. Since the prescription given gives at least one expression for the value at any given argument, such a map is automatically unique: there is no way that two different maps could both satisfy the prescription (and this is based merely on the *form* of the definition, not on any detailed arguments). However, the prescription actually gives *more than one* expression for the value at any given argument, since those arguments are classes, and the expression is in terms of a chosen member from that class. If two or more expressions for the value at the same argument would give different values, then the a map satisfying the prescription would not exist. This can be shown not to happen, and the conclusion is that the map is *well-defined*. So a more proper way to say this would be "it is *a priori* clear that such a map ($\tilde T$) is unique, and since it is well defined, it exists".